# How to fetch the Respose JSON data from Fetch/XHR using python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

If I search the data '`ditech process solutions private limited`' in search box in `https://lei-registrations.in/`portal then how can fetch the respose JSON data or request URL from Fetch/XHR using python using request module?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrGbV.png)

I tried to through selenium code but did not get:

```
import time

import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Create Chrome options with headless mode
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

# Set the path to the ChromeDriver executable
chrome_driver_path = "path/to/chromedriver"
# Create a Chrome webdriver with the specified options
driver = 
webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
url = 'https://lei-registrations.in/'
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(180)
print('URL open successfully in Chrome browser...')
searchBox = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='search']")
companyName = input("Type Company Name ")
time.sleep(2)
searchBox.send_keys(companyName)
print(f"{companyName} is processing..")
searchBox.submit()
driver.quit()
```

Can any one suggest?

Comment: Please [edit] your questin to include the link and code you have already tried.

Comment: @MendelG I edited my question, I used selenium but not get the respose JSON, please suggest how can fetch the response JSON from XHR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this example how to make a request to the server and get the results back in Json form:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

api_url = "https://lei-registrations.in/wp/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"

params = {
    "term": "ditech process solutions",  # <-- search term
    "country": "IN",
    "action": "get_search_companies",
}

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:122.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/122.0"
}

data = requests.get(api_url, params=params, headers=headers).json()

if data["success"]:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data["data"], "html.parser")
    for r in soup.select(".searchResults_title"):
        name = r.select_one(".searchResults_name").text
        number = r.select_one(".searchResults_number").text

        print(f"{name:<50} {number}")
```

Prints:

```
DITECH PROCESS SOLUTIONS PRIVATE LIMITED           U72300MH2008PTC179923
HITECH PROCESS CONTROLS PRIVATE LIMITED            U24231TN1988PTC015483
DYNACIATE PROCESS SOLUTIONS PRIVATELIMITED         U24233MH2011PTC216202
BRILLIANT PROCESS SOLUTIONS LLP                    AAE-8973
FUTURISTIC PROCESS SOLUTIONS PRIVATELIMITED        U72300KL2005PTC018914
VERTEXONE PROCESS SOLUTIONS PRIVATELIMITED         U74999DL2015PTC275822
INGENIOUS PROCESS SOLUTIONS PRIVATELIMITED         U74210TN2002PTC133188
AGILEDGE PROCESS SOLUTIONS PRIVATELIMITED          U74140KA2011PTC056535
SYNERGY PROCESS SOLUTIONS PRIVATELIMITED           U74999KL2010PTC025583
FLAIRTECH PROCESS SOLUTIONS PRIVATELIMITED         U74999PN2020PTC197082
PROCESS TECHNOLOGY SOLUTIONS PRIVATELIMITED        U29100MH2007PTC173767
FINELINE PROCESS SOLUTIONS PRIVATELIMITED          U29100PN2019PTC182625
SHIVASTE PROCESS SOLUTIONS PRIVATELIMITED          U51100DL2019PTC344406
DBN PROCESS SOLUTIONS PRIVATE LIMITED              U72200KL2008PTC022783
DIOSNA PROCESS SOLUTIONS PRIVATE LIMITED           U74900MH2015PTC270457
ECHEM PROCESS SOLUTIONS PRIVATE LIMITED            U24100TG2009PTC063720
ENFLOW PROCESS SOLUTIONS PRIVATE LIMITED           U31904PN2018PTC178859
EOGY PROCESS SOLUTIONS PRIVATE LIMITED             U74999MH2016PTC288991
EUNOIA PROCESS SOLUTIONS PRIVATE LIMITED           U72900RJ2017PTC056834
MSM PROCESS SOLUTIONS PRIVATE LIMITED              U74110MH2015PTC265506
QUANTA PROCESS SOLUTIONS PRIVATE LIMITED           U74120GJ2009PTC055943
METOREX ENGINEERING & PROCESS SOLUTIONS LLP        AAJ-5024
MLRS BUSINESS PROCESS SOLUTIONS LLP                AAG-6818
CSN PROCESS SOLUTIONS PRIVATE LIMITED              U72501AP2019PTC112846
SAWANT PROCESS SOLUTIONS PRIVATE LIMITED           U51397MH2004PTC145637
```

Comment: Andrej Kesely - Thanks for reply and one more question as you suggested is it possible to send the `term` keyword value dynamically using input.txt file? I will appreciated you.

Comment: @Yug Yes, of course. Read the file and then change the `params["term"]` value accordingly.

Comment: Andrej Kesely - Thanks for reply one more question how can we fetch the details only if attribute `data-has_lei=\"true\"`then fetch the attributes value e.g.`data-name, data-country_name, data-reg_code, data-address, data-lei_code, data-lei_registration_authority`, if you share with example how to fetch the details?

Comment: @Yug I suggest to open a new question here on StackOverflow (where you put what have you tried already etc...)

Comment: Andrej Kesely Thanks, I have create new question could you please check?